# MvvmCross Specifying a datacontext for pages

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-8, mvvmcross

I'm trying to develop a cross-platform app using mvvmcross.

More specifically I'm trying to port an app written for wp7 to all the other platforms. I've used blend for WP7 to design the animations and graphics of the "old version" app, and i would like to do it with mvvmcross.

But i don't know how to assign a data context to the page in order to be able to use blend (or visual studio gui) to create bindings and view the design of the page.

I'm SURE that i'm missing something huge...

Comment: I removed 'surely my question will be a dumb one...' - your question is good - I just learnt a lot from it - please continue asking good, positive questions, but without the negative starts :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For WindowsPhone, if you want to add design time data:

1. Open your solution in Blend
2. Open the page you want design time data on - e.g. `MyView`
3. Go to the Data tab/window (not sure how to describe this - it's top right)
4. In this, on the toolbar choose the little menu icon with 'Create Sample Data from Class'
5. In the dialog choose the ViewModel for you current page - e.g. `MyViewModel` for `MyView`
6. This will generate a sample set of data - you can edit this if you want to
7. Now in the XAML for your `MyView` page you can simply add the declaration:

   ```
       d:DataContext="{d:DesignData /SampleData/MyViewModelSampleData.xaml}"
   ```

That should just work.

---

I've never done this for Windows8 - I guessed it might be similar - although actually I don't know if it is - see questions like [Design time data in Windows Store app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12352724/design-time-data-in-windows-store-app)

Comment: Thanks Stuart! I'll try as soon as i can! Can i ask you how you usually work to design the graphics and the animations of your windows (Phone/RT) Apps?

Comment: I avoid the area completely - this is me using a visual design surface - http://catoverflow.com/cOSFFyOK

Comment: Ahahahhahahah...so you're a fruit ninja master! =)

Comment: For windows phone worked perfectly! I'll have to find a way to do it in WinRT.

Comment: please blog when you find a way

Comment: Actually a not-so-functional but easy way to do this is creating an ad-hoc class containing all the sample data, as stated here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14275891/windows-store-app-design-time-datacontext). I know that it can be a long task...but it can save a lot of design time.

Comment: Just as a side note, i've reused the same class also in my WP7 project in order to have a common data set to use during design...it would be great to been able to reuse this also for monotouch/monodroid development...but actually i really don't know if it's possible at all to have design time data in XCode or Xamarin's monodroid designer =)

Comment: The hero in me wants to go the other way - to create a tool that can create classes from the WP XML that Blend generates...